# How to pass DTO to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to pass to the controller DTO object. My DTO object with public methods and it always gets null values:

```
public class MyDto {
    public String name;
    public String age
}

// MyController
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String data(MyDto obj) { 
        obj.name // always null;
    }
}
```

but if I add getters and setters to `MyDto` all works fine.
How can I pass `MyDto` only with public fields (I couldn't change this object because it is in another jar which I don't have access to)?

Comment: How are you passing the data? JSON/XML or through a form? Please add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be adding getters/setters to `MyDto` class as you said. If you can't change that class I think you can achieve your goal configuring the object mapper of your application adding a custom deserialiser to tell Jackson how to create a MyDto from a json string.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to exrtend the DTO class and add getter/setter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extend the MyDto class and add getters and setters to your extended DTO.
2. Use `@RequestBody` in your method paramater like the following:

   ```
   @RestController
   public class MyController {
       @PostMapping("/")
       public String data(@RequestBody MyDto obj) {
           System.out.println(obj.name);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change ```@Controller``` to ```@RestController```

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Arun answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65422733/14231239), if you want to use `@Controller` annotation instead of `@RestController`, you must replace `@RequestBody` with `@ModelAttribute` like this

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping("/")
    public String data(@ModelAttribute MyDto obj) {
        System.out.println(obj.name);
    }
}
```